# Parse IP:Port from string with characters after the port #

Tags: php, regex

I need a little help with this one and my RegEx knowledge is a little lacking with this one.

I have a proxy list that I'm trying to parse and separate the IP and port number from the string.

The string being read looks like this.(example 1)

```
121.121.121.121:8081    2.103384    Китай   high    05-07-2014 09:25:17
```

and sometimes look like (example 2)

```
222.222.222.222:8081
```

When I use this code.

```
preg_match_all('@[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.@',$ip,$results);
$output = (preg_split('/:/',$results));
$ip = $output['0'];
$port = $output['1'];
```

It works great when there is just a IP:Port like in example #2 but in example #1
its also grabbing everything past the space so the port number looks like "8081 2.103384    Китай   high    05-07-2014 09:25:17"

Is there a regex pattern I can use to have it stop at a space if it see's one?

Comment: are you sure about your snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a split, you're only matching what you don't want; in this case you would want to have a match though.

The following matching expression should work in your case:

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d[\d.]+):(\d+)\b/', $proxy, $matches)) {
    $ip = $matches[1];
    $port = $matches[2];
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble matching a tab instead of a colon. `\t` does not seem to work

Comment: @zoltar have you tried using double quotes instead of single quotes as the string delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

This regex would match the ip-address and the port number,

```
\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,5}\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rE9nW6/5)

From that you could split it easily.

OR

you could use a `preg_match` function,

```
<?php
$str = '121.121.121.121:8081    2.103384    Китай   high    05-07-2014 09:25:17';
if (preg_match('~\b([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{1,5}\b)~', $str, $matches)) {
    $ip = $matches[1];
    $port = $matches[2];
}
echo "$ip\n";
echo "$port\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
121.121.121.121
8081
```

Comment: Since port number could range upto 5 digits (65535 max), `{1,5}` would be perfect?

Answer (score 1):

As there is no need to validate IP addresses at this level, there's a shorter way to match them:

```
(\d+(?(?!:)\.)){4}:\d+
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/gD7qX1/2)

***PHP***:

```
preg_match_all('@(\d+(?(?!:)\.)){4}:\d+@', $ip, $results);
```